# custom ListView - get id of item when i click on a button located inside the list

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom ListView with a button inside it, when i click on this button, the onItemClickListener() is not called, the button's onClick() method is called instead.
What i want to achieve, is to get the id of the list item where is located the button i clicked on (i need this id to delete the good entry from my database).

Here is my adapter :

```
sa = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.list_mission,
                        new String[] {"marque", "date"}, new int[] {R.id.list_vehicule, R.id.list_date});
```

Thank you !

Comment: Post your custom adapter.

Comment: @bumblebeez check my answer by setting false to both you will be able to click on OnitemClick as well as button click listener ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `interface`. Create your custom class like this :

```
public interface MyCustomClickListener{
      public void onMyClickListener(int id){}
}
```

In your custom adapter you can use this `interface` like this :

```
private MyCustomClickListener mMyClickListener;

public MyAdapter(Activity activity){
    try {
        mMyClickListener = (MyCustomClickListener) activity;
    } catch(ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity + " must implements MyCustomClickListener");
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    Button mMyBtn = // initialise Button
    mMyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            mMyClickListener.onMyClickListener(position);
        }

    };
}
```

And in your `Activity` :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyCustomClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onMyClickListener(int id){
        // your id
    }

}
```

This should work like a charm! : )

Comment: What do you mean by 'in your custom adapter' ?

Comment: your ListView adapter.

Comment: the only moment where I use my simpleadapter are the 2 lines i posted in my question, i don't really understand how i am supposed to use this part of your code ! sorry, but i'm very new to android development

Comment: You should create a custom adapter, to use this method. here are some examples how to achieve this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You may use `setTag`

For example:There is a button_0 in item_0

in `getView`:

```
button_0.setTag(position)
```

in your `onClick`

you can get the position by `v.getTag()`